# Python pandas - read_csv Dataframe is dropping values from columns

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

first off I know the below sample is off in indentation and if someone can point me in the right direction for posting DataFrames correctly I'd be very grateful.

Now, I have a dataframe as below:

```html
Ticker_x Date Close_x Ticker_y Close_y Lead_Lag Ticker 15M_Trend Bollinger_1SD Bollinger_2SD Bollinger_and_Trend_1SD Bollinger_and_Trend_2SD 
ES M7 6/2/2017 3:29 2433.75 VX M7-CF 11.6 N       
ES M7 6/2/2017 4:29 2434.75 VX M7-CF 11.6 Short       
ES M7 6/2/2017 5:29 2435 VX M7-CF 11.55 N       
ES M7 6/2/2017 6:29 2434.25 VX M7-CF 11.57 N       
ES M7 6/2/2017 7:29 2430.25 VX M7-CF 11.7 Short       
ES M7 6/2/2017 8:29 2430.75 VX M7-CF 11.58 Short       
ES M7 6/2/2017 9:29 2433.25 VX M7-CF 11.63 Short       
ES M7 6/2/2017 10:29 2436.75 VX M7-CF 11.61 Short       
ES M7 6/2/2017 11:29 2436.75 VX M7-CF 11.57 Short       
ES M7 6/2/2017 12:29 2435.75 VX M7-CF 11.67 Short       
ES M7 6/2/2017 13:29 2437.75 VX M7-CF 11.64 Short       
ES M7 6/2/2017 14:29 2437.75 VX M7-CF 11.63 Short
```

I'm creating this dataframe from read_csv function of another file, and only including columns outlined below. Note that I'm picking up the most recent file from a folder with 'glob':

```
filenameA = max(glob.iglob(r"C:\Users\cost9\OneDrive\Documents\PYTHON\Daily Tasks\Pairs Trading\VX_ES\CSV\15M\Lead_Lag\*.csv"))

AggregatedA = pd.read_csv(filenameA, usecols=['Ticker_x', 'Date', 'Close_x', 'Ticker_y', 'Close_y', 'Lead_Lag', 'Ticker', '15M_Trend', 'Bollinger_1SD', 'Bollinger_2SD', 'Bollinger_and_Trend_1SD', 'Bollinger_and_Trend_2SD'])
p2 = r"C:\Users\cost9\OneDrive\Documents\PYTHON\Daily Tasks\Individual Trading\VX\CSV\Aggregated\VX_ES_15M\blah2.csv"
AggregatedA.to_csv(path_or_buf = p2)
```

So that new file 'blah2' is the csv file shown above. You'll note that like 7 or 8 columns on the far right are blank. These should not be blank. They are not blank in the original file I picked up from 'filenameA'.

I.e. they have a bunch of values for 'Ticker', '15M_Trend' and the other columns. For some reason pandas aren't picking up those values and I'm not sure why. Help is much appreciated!

edit: here's the original lines of the dataframe:

```html
Ticker_x Date Open_x High_x Low_x Close_x Volume_x Open Interest_x Ticker_y Open_y High_y Low_y Close_y Volume_y Open Interest_y ES_returns VX_returns Beta Pairs_Spread zscore Pairs_Spread_Mean Pairs_Spread_sdev ES_percent_change ES_difference VX_percent_change ES_CC VX_CC pairs_spread pairs_zscore ES_Inverse_price ES__Inverse_percent_change Inverse_ES_CC Inverse_pairs_spread Inverse_pairs_zscore Lead_Lag Ticker Open High Low Close Volume Open Interest Index_Num Rolling_OLS_Coefficient 15M_Long Upper_Sdev_Value Lower_Sdev_Value Intercept Middle Sdev Lower_Sdev_value 15M_Trend Rolling_mean Rolling_std Upper_Band Lower_Band Upper_Band_2 Lower_Band_2 Bollinger_1SD Bollinger_2SD Bollinger_and_Trend_1SD Bollinger_and_Trend_2SD Trend_and_LL
ES M7 6/2/2017 3:29 2433.25 2433.75 2433 2433.75 3419 0 VX M7-CF 11.55 11.6 11.53 11.6 253 0 0 0.001727116 -6.946994692     0 0 0.001727116 -0.27013895 -0.27013895 2514.335138 2.733208694 2138.25 0 0.270990395 2218.835138 -1.144384967 N VX M7-CF 11.55 11.6 11.53 11.6 253 0 1868 -0.006269114  27.09349175  23.18140592 23.10868419 3.984807553 19.12387664 Short 11.7912 0.1573199 11.9485199 11.6338801 12.1058398 11.4765602 Long N N N N
ES M7 6/2/2017 4:29 2435 2435.5 2434.75 2434.75 2847 0 VX M7-CF 11.59 11.6 11.55 11.6 118 0 0.000410889 0 -6.94464418     0.000410889 1 0 -0.434541317 -0.434541317 2515.307872 2.759879939 2137.25 -0.000467672 0.43443517 2217.807872 -1.197621083 Short VX M7-CF 11.59 11.6 11.55 11.6 118 0 1869 -0.006344733  27.26010073  23.31610124 23.24250234 4.017598384 19.22490396 Short 11.7868 0.159558575 11.94635857 11.62724143 12.10591715 11.46768285 Long N N N Short
ES M7 6/2/2017 5:29 2436.25 2436.5 2435 2435 5979 0 VX M7-CF 11.55 11.6 11.5 11.55 716 0 0.00010268 -0.004310345 -6.945304375     0.00010268 0.25 -0.004310345 -0.364155097 -0.364155097 2515.218266 2.75742302 2137 -0.000116973 0.364203518 2217.218266 -1.228176348 N VX M7-CF 11.55 11.6 11.5 11.55 716 0 1870 -0.006422122  27.43061644  23.45376171 23.37958619 4.051030244 19.32855595 Short 11.7814 0.162944964 11.94434496 11.61845504 12.10728993 11.45551007 Long N N N N
ES M7 6/2/2017 6:29 2434.5 2435 2433.75 2434.25 11821 0 VX M7-CF 11.5 11.65 11.5 11.57 1919 0 -0.000308008 0.001731602 -6.943255051     -0.000308008 -0.75 0.001731602 -0.391364705 -0.391364705 2514.583461 2.74001741 2137.75 0.000350959 0.391371805 2218.083461 -1.183339232 N VX M7-CF 11.5 11.65 11.5 11.57 1919 0 1871 -0.006492588  27.58935246  23.57945638 23.50433714 4.08501532 19.41932182 Short 11.7764 0.165551151 11.94195115 11.61084885 12.1075023 11.4452977 Long N N N N
ES M7 6/2/2017 7:29 2431.25 2431.75 2430 2430.25 16785 0 VX M7-CF 11.6 11.75 11.58 11.7 3737 0 -0.001643217 0.011235955 -6.941089619     -0.001643217 -4 0.011235955 -0.795190709 -0.795190709 2511.460749 2.654396241 2141.75 0.001871126 0.79514286 2222.960749 -0.930583022 Short VX M7-CF 11.6 11.75 11.58 11.7 3737 0 1872 -0.006552806  27.73075716  23.68800858 23.61134075 4.119416411 19.49192434 Short 11.776 0.165714286 11.94171429 11.61028571 12.10742857 11.44457143 N N N N Short
ES M7 6/2/2017 8:29 2430.25 2431 2429 2430.75 37511 0 VX M7-CF 11.7 11.8 11.53 11.58 15635 0 0.00020574 -0.01025641 -6.944443722     0.00020574 0.5 -0.01025641 -0.801967629 -0.801967629 2511.166658 2.646332626 2141.25 -0.000233454 0.801808413 2221.666658 -0.997646802 Short VX M7-CF 11.7 11.8 11.53 11.58 15635 0 1873 -0.006629471  27.90272657  23.82506069 23.74829141 4.154435156 19.59385626 Short 11.773 0.167907287 11.94090729 11.60509271 12.10881457 11.43718543 Long N N N Short
ES M7 6/2/2017 9:29 2432.25 2433.75 2432.25 2433.25 26047 0 VX M7-CF 11.55 11.7 11.55 11.63 7148 0 0.001028489 0.004317789 -6.902663206     0.001028489 2.5 0.004317789 -0.50559849 -0.50559849 2513.527973 2.711077152 2138.75 -0.001167542 0.506119457 2219.027973 -1.134391675 Short VX M7-CF 11.55 11.7 11.55 11.63 7148 0 1874 -0.006703266  28.06957526  23.95751485 23.87955587 4.190019391 19.68953648 Short 11.7706 0.169096157 11.93969616 11.60150384 12.10879231 11.43240769 N N N N Short
ES M7 6/2/2017 10:29 2435.75 2437 2435.5 2436.75 31594 0 VX M7-CF 11.65 11.65 11.55 11.61 5090 0 0.001438405 -0.00171969 -6.862573345     0.001438405 3.5 -0.00171969 -0.494655304 -0.494655304 2516.424477 2.790495933 2135.25 -0.00163647 0.495088995 2214.924477 -1.347047627 Short VX M7-CF 11.65 11.65 11.55 11.61 5090 0 1875 -0.006773515  28.23118528  24.08370058 24.00506007 4.226125209 19.77893486 Short 11.7608 0.163729992 11.92452999 11.59707001 12.08825998 11.43334002 N N N N Short
ES M7 6/2/2017 11:29 2436 2437 2435.5 2436.75 25538 0 VX M7-CF 11.65 11.65 11.55 11.57 2278 0 0 -0.003445306 -6.86522263     0 0 -0.003445306 -0.46654779 -0.46654779 2516.180626 2.783809828 2135.25 0 0.466999626 2214.680626 -1.359684729 Short VX M7-CF 11.65 11.65 11.55 11.57 2278 0 1876 -0.00683482  28.37745101  24.19388406 24.11480519 4.262645818 19.85215938 Short 11.7512 0.160466666 11.91166667 11.59073333 12.07213333 11.43026667 Long N N N Short
ES M7 6/2/2017 12:29 2437.75 2438.75 2435.5 2435.75 37037 0 VX M7-CF 11.58 11.69 11.55 11.67 4309 0 -0.000410383 0.008643042 -6.890566028     -0.000410383 -1 0.008643042 -0.503091577 -0.503091577 2516.162906 2.783323958 2136.25 0.000468329 0.503595438 2216.662906 -1.25695683 Short VX M7-CF 11.58 11.69 11.55 11.67 4309 0 1877 -0.006883805  28.50205329  24.28297379 24.20263978 4.299413516 19.90322626 Short 11.7436 0.154929345 11.89852935 11.58867065 12.05345869 11.43374131 N N N N Short
ES M7 6/2/2017 13:29 2437.75 2438.5 2437 2437.75 26228 0 VX M7-CF 11.68 11.7 11.55 11.64 8570 0 0.000821102 -0.002570694 -6.88244494     0.000821102 2 -0.002570694 -0.520801285 -0.520801285 2517.861659 2.82990182 2134.25 -0.00093622 0.521308056 2214.361659 -1.376214577 Short VX M7-CF 11.68 11.7 11.55 11.64 8570 0 1878 -0.006929786  28.62236572  24.3666349 24.2859722 4.336393523 19.94957867 Short 11.734 0.145728291 11.87972829 11.58827171 12.02545658 11.44254342 N N N N Short
ES M7 6/2/2017 14:29 2437.75 2437.75 2437.75 2437.75 1 0 VX M7-CF 11.6 11.7 11.55 11.63 28177 0 0 -0.000859107 -6.904693941     0 0 -0.000859107 -0.516701901 -0.516701901 2518.051591 2.835109521 2134.25 0 0.517232222 2214.551591 -1.36637174 Short VX M7-CF 11.6 11.7 11.55 11.63 28177 0 1879 -0.006969382  28.73142917  24.4389793 24.35792539 4.37350378 19.98442161 Short 11.724 0.13474087 11.85874087 11.58925913 11.99348174 11.45451826 N N N N Short
```

EDIT: Here's the new code, based on the below suggestion:

```
AggregatedA = pd.read_csv(max(glob.iglob(r"C:\Users\cost9\OneDrive\Documents\PYTHON\Daily Tasks\Pairs Trading\VX_ES\CSV\15M\Lead_Lag\*.csv")), usecols=['Ticker_x', 'Date', 'Close_x', 'Ticker_y', 'Close_y', 'Lead_Lag', 'Ticker', '15M_Trend', 'Bollinger_1SD', 'Bollinger_2SD', 'Bollinger_and_Trend_1SD', 'Bollinger_and_Trend_2SD'], delimiter='\t')

AggregatedA.to_csv(r"C:\Users\cost9\OneDrive\Documents\PYTHON\Daily Tasks\Individual Trading\VX\CSV\Aggregated\VX_ES_15M\blah2.csv")
```

Which gives the error:

```
ValueError: Usecols do not match names.
```

edit: I also tried using delimiter=',' rather than delimiter='\t', which got rid of the error. However, the right columns remain blank.

Comment: Could you provide the actual input csv file and not just the output one?

Comment: Hey, I added the original lines at the bottom of the post but note that I'm having trouble formatting the lines to get the column headers to match the data

Comment: @ColeStarbuck #1 first commenter's name is "fuglede" not "hey".  #2 fuglede asked for the actual csv.  We don't want you to format it, we want the raw file contents.  Something is happening in between the file contents and parsing.  We can't figure out what that is if you keep giving us stuff after it's been parsed, either by you or pandas.

Comment: @piRSquared I'm not sure how to upload CSV file onto stack overflow. I've been looking at how to do it but it looks like it's not an available feature.

Comment: Copy the first 20 lines of text from the csv and paste them into the post...  after that, highlight the newly pasted text and click the button on the post edit tool bar that looks like **{}**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the input is as given, it is surprising that `pandas` parses the dataframe at all, as the delimiter should be given explicitly. Doing that, the code works as it should. If `in.txt` contains the lines, you provided, then running

```
In [26]: AggregatedA = pd.read_csv('in.txt', usecols=['Ticker_x', 'Date', 'Close_x', 'Ticker_y', 'Close_y', 'Lead_Lag', 'Ticker', '15M_Trend', 'Bollinger_1SD', 'Bollinger_2SD', 'Bollinger_and_Trend_1SD', 'Bollinger_and_Trend_2SD'], delimiter='\t')

In [25]: AggregatedA.to_csv('out.txt')
```

will give an `out.txt` with the following contents:

```
$ cat out.txt
,Ticker_x,Date,Close_x,Ticker_y,Close_y,Lead_Lag,Ticker,15M_Trend,Bollinger_1SD,Bollinger_2SD,Bollinger_and_Trend_1SD,Bollinger_and_Trend_2SD
0,ES M7,6/2/2017 3:29,2433.75,VX M7-CF,11.6,N,VX M7-CF,Short,Long,N,N,N
1,ES M7,6/2/2017 4:29,2434.75,VX M7-CF,11.6,Short,VX M7-CF,Short,Long,N,N,N
2,ES M7,6/2/2017 5:29,2435.0,VX M7-CF,11.55,N,VX M7-CF,Short,Long,N,N,N
3,ES M7,6/2/2017 6:29,2434.25,VX M7-CF,11.57,N,VX M7-CF,Short,Long,N,N,N
4,ES M7,6/2/2017 7:29,2430.25,VX M7-CF,11.7,Short,VX M7-CF,Short,N,N,N,N
5,ES M7,6/2/2017 8:29,2430.75,VX M7-CF,11.58,Short,VX M7-CF,Short,Long,N,N,N
6,ES M7,6/2/2017 9:29,2433.25,VX M7-CF,11.63,Short,VX M7-CF,Short,N,N,N,N
7,ES M7,6/2/2017 10:29,2436.75,VX M7-CF,11.61,Short,VX M7-CF,Short,N,N,N,N
8,ES M7,6/2/2017 11:29,2436.75,VX M7-CF,11.57,Short,VX M7-CF,Short,Long,N,N,N
9,ES M7,6/2/2017 12:29,2435.75,VX M7-CF,11.67,Short,VX M7-CF,Short,N,N,N,N
10,ES M7,6/2/2017 13:29,2437.75,VX M7-CF,11.64,Short,VX M7-CF,Short,N,N,N,N
11,ES M7,6/2/2017 14:29,2437.75,VX M7-CF,11.63,Short,VX M7-CF,Short,N,N,N,N
```

Comment: I'm getting a new error when (I think) I replicate what you suggested...posted in the original